# JSON Web Service not appearing in /api/jsonws

Tags: liferay

I m new to liferay perform crud operation but my create method is not appering in api/jsonws . I also check my service is active by lb gogo shell  command

Comment: How did you create your module project? Is it a servicebuilder project? There are some examples and templates when using BladeCLI. Please have a look at: [Rest Template](https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-1/rest-template). Also maybe [this blog post](https://community.liferay.com/en/blogs/-/blogs/liferay-jax-rs-service) helps. If it is a servicebuilder project you need to add your method to the public/remote API

Comment: Assume it "works for us" - give *all* steps that we'd need to reproduce your issue, otherwise we can't do anything else than pointing you to documentation, which you're probably already working after. Please edit your question and add *a lot* more information. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for information on *what to include*. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for information on *what to avoid*.

Comment: yes it is service builder project@Andre Albert . can you help me how to add method to the public,remote API. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

For ServiceBuilder operations, please check if you have `remote-service="true"` on your entity (attributes) inside the service.xml file. If not, please add this attribute and rerun servicebuilder.

Open your {EntityName}ServiceImpl (inside of the .service.impl package) and add your operations here.

Finally, rerun servicebuilder and deploy your app. When using api/jsonws - make sure you select the right context name with the dropdown.